# Migrate Sybase SQL Server/11.0.3.2 ( Sybase 11.0) to Sybase 11.9.2

Tags: sql-server, database, sybase

I would like to migrate a instance of SQL Server/11.0.3.2 to Sybase 11.9.2 (i want use SSMA after that). There is no documentation on this subject on the web because it's too old (1997).

I only want migrate 3 databases of my instance. I try to dump a db to Sybase 12.5.4, not work, ddlgen not work on 11.0.3.2. With the system table, i can recreate the SQL script for table, view, procedure... and then i bcp the data. But i think it's not a good way, it's too long and not safe...

An other solution: upgrade the server to 11.9.2 (or more), but as i say, i only want migrate 3 databases.

If sombody have an other way to do that, it's will be a great help.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Is this Sybase ASE?  Those version numbers are very old!  For Sybase ASE you should be using Sybase 15.7.

Comment: @AbeCrabtree Yes, it's sybase ASE 11.0

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take a database dump from 11.0.3 and load it into a later ASE version. It is not formally supported, but I have done this successfully for ASE 12.5.

Comment: i try to dump database between 11.0.3 to 12.5.4 but it's don't work, the database stay offline,(online database -> error) when i restart the server, the database is online but i haven't table... However procedure and user is correctly dump.